# Tensorboard projector not working on colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorboard

The GPU version of Tensorboard is having certain issues in Colab although the CPU version works alright. I could not find much from the docs though. This is the error
[image]

Also, I tried the following for installation
[image]

As you can see, I tried with both GPU and non-GPU versions and it does not work till I disable the GPU from runtime. Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'd recommend filing an issue on the [TensorBoard GitHub issues page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues).

Comment: Cross-link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2350